Inductive assumption in inductive case
likely stupid question here, I'm sure, but I have been trying fruitlessly with little success to figure this problem out. Here is a toy example. Suppose we have this.
def f (x : Nat) := match x with
| 0 => 0
| n + 1 =>
  have : x = n + 1 := by sorry
  3

How do we prove that statement, that x = n + 1? This seems like it should be obvious. The full example where this comes up is of course more involved -- if anyone thinks I can do it easily another way, please be my guest; I am trying to prove soundness for a subset of propositional logic with just # and ->.
inductive Expr where
| bot : Expr
| var (s : String) : Expr
| imp (p q : Expr) : Expr

infixl:80 " ==> " => Expr.imp
notation "⊥" => Expr.bot

inductive TruthVal where
| T : TruthVal
| F : TruthVal

def eval (e : Expr) (env : String -> TruthVal) : TruthVal := match e with
| ⊥ => TruthVal.F
| Expr.var s => env s
| p ==> q => match eval p env with
  | TruthVal.T => eval q env
  | TruthVal.F => TruthVal.T

def Set u := u -> Prop
def Set.union (u1 : Set u) (u2 : Set u) : Set u := fun u' => u1 u' ∨ u2 u'
def Set.add (u1 : Set u) (u2 : u) : Set u := fun u' => u1 u' ∨ u' = u2
def Set.subset (s S : Set u) : Prop := ∀ u', s u' -> S u'
def Set.unionSubset (eq : Set.union x y = z) : Set.subset x z :=
  fun u g =>
    let hp : x u := by
      subst eq
      exact g
    let or : x u ∨ y u := Or.intro_left (y u) hp
    by
      subst eq
      rw [union]
      exact or

inductive Proof : Set Expr -> Expr -> Type u where
| premise : premises q -> Proof premises q
| doubleNegation : Proof premises (Expr.imp (Expr.imp p Expr.bot) Expr.bot) -> Proof premises p
| direct : Proof (Set.add premises p) q -> Proof premises (Expr.imp p q)
| modusPonens
  (proof1 : Proof prems1 (Expr.imp p q))
  (proof2 : Proof prems2 p)
  (eq_proof : Set.union prems1 prems2 = premises) : Proof premises q

def entails (Γ : Set Expr) (φ : Expr) : Prop :=
  ∀ model : String -> TruthVal,
  (∀ premise : Expr, Γ premise -> eval premise model = TruthVal.T) ->
  eval φ model = TruthVal.T

infixl:65 " ⊢ " => Proof
infixl:65 " ⊨ " => entails

def Proof.hypotheses : prems ⊢ concl -> Set Expr := fun _ => prems
def Proof.conclusion : prems ⊢ concl -> Expr := fun _ => concl

theorem Proof.soundness : Γ ⊢ φ -> Γ ⊨ φ :=
  fun (p : Γ ⊢ φ)
    (model : String -> TruthVal)
    (premisesHold : ∀ premise : Expr, Γ premise -> eval premise model = TruthVal.T)
    => match p with
  | premise proof => premisesHold φ proof
  | doubleNegation proof =>
    let ih : Γ ⊨ φ ==> ⊥ ==> ⊥ := proof.soundness
    let result : TruthVal.T = eval φ model := calc
      TruthVal.T = eval (φ ==> ⊥ ==> ⊥) model := Eq.symm (ih model premisesHold)
      _ = eval φ model :=
      by
        repeat rw [eval]
        cases (eval φ model)
        repeat simp
    Eq.symm result
  | direct subproof =>
    let ih := subproof.soundness
    by
      rename_i assumption conclusion
      rw [eval]
      let allPremsHoldIfAssumptionTrue :
        eval assumption model = TruthVal.T -> ∀ premise : Expr, (Set.add Γ assumption) premise -> eval premise model = TruthVal.T
        := fun hyp premise =>
          by
            rw [Set.add]
            intro or
            cases or with
            | inl h => have g := premisesHold premise h; exact g
            | inr h => rw [h]; exact hyp
      cases (eval assumption model) with
      | F => simp
      | T =>
        simp
        exact ih model (allPremsHoldIfAssumptionTrue sorry)
  | modusPonens proof1 proof2 eq => sorry

In particular, I am looking for something to deal with the first sorry -- that is, a term of eval assumption model = TruthVal.T, which seems like it should be obvious to get.
Many thanks in advance.

I think this is what you're looking for.

Yes this is exactly what I'm looking for, thank you!
